# String to clipboard, but without the new line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Working on a python project where I need to copy a string to the clipboard for the user to use on other applications based on inputs. Right now I have the following:

```
os.system(f"echo {phrase}| clip")
```

for now it works fine within the python console, but whenever I do a ctrl+v/right-click+paste function it will paste the {phrase} but also include a new line right below it which throws off the other applications.

I've tried using str.strip() and str.rstrip() on {phrase} but it doesn't make a difference. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which operating system?  There are APIs available to manipulate the clipboard directly, without using a shell hack.

Comment: It's `echo` that's adding the newline; nothing you can possibly do with `phrase` will change that.  You need to issue the command as `echo -n {phrase}` - but note that there will still be issues if your string includes spaces or other characters that are meaningful to the shell.  It would be better to use the `pyperclip` module, which works on multiple systems, and knows how to deal with such issues.

Comment: @jasonharper - I've just tried using the -n flag, doesn't seem to help, and without admin privileges I can't pip in pyperclip. I went with a different response and it worked well. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is `echo` prints out a newline by default; add the `-n` switch to make it not to.

**HOWEVER, DON'T DO THIS:**

```
os.system(f"echo -n {phrase} | clip")
```

because if `phrase` contains malicious user input, you've got a (remote) code execution vulnerability at your hands (consider `| somethingevil`).

Instead, use `subprocess.run()` with `input`, which does the same as piping from `echo` to `clip`, and you don't need `echo` at all.

```
subprocess.run("clip", input=phrase, check=True, encoding="utf-8")
```

Better still, you could use the [`pyperclip`](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/) module:

```
pyperclip.copy('The text to be copied to the clipboard.')
```

Comment: The subprocess.run method worked out great, thank you!